# EF Code First Flexible Relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to set up a flexible one-to-many relationship in EF. Imagine we have the following POCO classes:

```
public class EntityA
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Event> Events { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Event> Events { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid EntityId { get; set; }
}
```

I want the `Event` class to link to either Entity through the `EntityId` propery. So it's not a normal One-To-Many relationship.

I don't need any relationship properties on the Event side, but I would like there to be an `IEnumerable<Event> Events` property in each of the two Entity classes, which will allow me to grab a list of linked events for any entity I choose.

I'm using `EntityTypeConfiguration<T>` maps but I need help working out the relationships on this.

Comment: See *polymorphic associations*.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look.